# Firebase Cloud Functions: Difference between onRequest and onCall

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Going through the docs, I encountered:

> ...you can call functions directly with an HTTP request or a [call from the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).
>
> ~ [source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/#lifecycle_of_a_background_function)

there *(link in the quote)* is a mention about `functions.https.onCall`.

But in the tutorial [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), another function `functions.https.onRequest` is used, so which one should I use and why? What is the difference/similarity between them?

Documentation for `functions.https` is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https#.onCall).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the new Firebase Cloud Functions https.onCall trigger better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475667/is-the-new-firebase-cloud-functions-https-oncall-trigger-better)

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson, but I have read that question prior to asking this one and it did not help me understand the topic better.

Comment: I don't think there's anything else to understand. What is your specific confusion?

Comment: I'll add that making a decision about which one to use is entirely dependent on your actual task at hand, and personal preference.  One is not strictly better than the other.  They serve different purposes.  Choose the one that suits the situation.

Comment: @DougStevenson For one, there seems to be a difference in how those functions can be invoked. One via url, other using an in-app call.

Comment: Yes, they are also different in that respect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you check my answer for possible mistakes please? Thanks!

Answer (score 211, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) for those is really helpful, but from the view of an amateur, the described differences were confusing at first.

- **Both types**, when deployed, are assigned with a unique HTTPS endpoint URL and can be accessed directly using an https client.
- However, there is one important difference in the way how they are ***supposed* to be called**.

  - `onCall`: from the client's `firebase.functions()`
  - `onRequest`: via standard https client (e.g. `fetch()` API in JS)

## onCall

- Can be invoked (and this is also the main purpose) directly from the client app.

  ```
   functions.httpsCallable('getUser')({uid})
     .then(r => console.log(r.data.email))
  ```
- It is implemented with user-provided `data` and *automagic* `context`.

  ```
   export const getUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
     if (!context.auth) return {status: 'error', code: 401, message: 'Not signed in'}
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // find a user by data.uid and return the result
       resolve(user)
     })
   })
  ```
- The `context` automagically [contains metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext.html) about the request such as `uid` and `token`.
- Input `data` and `response` objects are automatically (de)serialized.

## onRequest

- [Firebase onRequest Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#onrequest)
- Serves mostly as an Express API endpoint.
- It is implemented with express `Request` and `Response` objects.

  ```
   export const getUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     // verify user from req.headers.authorization etc.
     res.status(401).send('Authentication required.')
     // if authorized
     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
     res.send(JSON.stringify(user))
   })
  ```
- Depends on user-provided authorization headers.
- You are responsible for input and response data.

Read more here [Is the new Firebase Cloud Functions https.onCall trigger better?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49476648/985454)

Comment: How can you call an onRequest function? Or onCall functions are the only ones that can be called from the client?

Comment: @JoseTapizquent You can call it using `fetch()`, it's just an API endpoint.

Comment: onRequest creates a standard API endpoint, and you'll use whatever methods your client-side code normally uses to make. HTTP requests to interact with them. onCall creates a callable. Once you get used to them, onCall is less effort to write, but you don't have all the flexibility you might be used to.

Comment: Is it possible to call a function which is registered with onRequest from the client directly, without making an HTTP request?

Comment: Docs says "With callables, Firebase Authentication tokens, FCM tokens, and App Check tokens, when available, are automatically included in requests.", does it also mean that `onCall` is callable and `onRequest` is not because as you mentioned `onCall`'s `context` has info about `uid` but `onRequest` doesn't.

Comment: @iDecode IIRC what you do with the provided metadata in the request handler is up to you. You could call a *callable* function with `fetch()` and return a response or reject it because `context.auth` is missing. And I suspect that you could theoretically *call* an `onRequest` method too and parse the provided metadata yourself. When you are *calling* a *callable* (`onCall`) it's just so much easier than *fetching* from an express endpoint (`onRequest`).

Comment: For all those looking at this answer after years, if you use v2 functions it takes only one request parameter.

Answer (score 15):

The main difference between **onCall** and **onRequest** for the client is the way they are invoked from client side.
When you define a function using **onCall** e.g.

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
  return ...
});
```

you can invoke it on the client side using the firebase function client SDK e.g.

```
// on the client side, you need to import functions client lib
// then you invoke it like this:
const addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
addMessage({ text: messageText })
  .then((result) => {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.        
  });
```

more info for onCall: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

But if you define your function using **onRequest** e.g.

```
exports.addMesssage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) { 
  //...   
  res.send(...); 
}
```

you can call it using normal JS fetch API (no need to import firebase functions client lib on the client code) e.g.

```
fetch('<your cloud function endpoint>/addMessage').then(...)
```

this is the big difference that you need to consider when deciding on how to define your functions on the server.

more info for onRequest: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events