# flutter firebase functions onCall method not showing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHnL4.png)

it's showing onRequest() not onCall().
any idea?
I have added screenshot.

Comment: can anyone help me? I am trying to resolve this issue for very long.

Answer (score 0):

onCall is usually invoked from the client app rather than the backend, that's why you only see onRequest as a suggestion and not onCall. You should use onRequest here. Read this for more on their differences: [Firebase Cloud Functions: Difference between onRequest and onCall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066434/firebase-cloud-functions-difference-between-onrequest-and-oncall)

Comment: callable functions are deployed using functions.https.onCall. I can use onRequest with http, but I need onCall method.