# onCall vs on onRequest expected behavior?

Tags: typescript, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I've been working on an app for a good while and now I've started working on an api gateway in firebase. I'm using axios to download data which works fine in onRequest but if I do the same in onCall it returns `<null>`. Are you not supposed to use onCall to download data? Excuse my question, I've googled for hours :)

Here's my code example

```js
export const testFunc = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    try {
      const data = () => {
        return axios.get(
          "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&locale=en",
        );
      };

      return {
        status: 200,
        data: data,
      };
    } catch (err) {
      return {
        status: 500,
        error: err,
      };
    }
  });
});
```

Tried using an onRequest which works but I want the authentication check that onCall gives

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Cloud Functions: Difference between onRequest and onCall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066434/firebase-cloud-functions-difference-between-onrequest-and-oncall)

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe I don't understand it but how it reads to me is that onCall can be called from the SDK while onRequest can be called by anyone with a URL. Says nothing about not being able to download api data in onCall?
Maybe it's fine to use onRequest if I add AppCheck for security. I just don't want anyone to able to use my endpoints

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to me to use `cors()` middleware for `onCall`

Comment: As @Phill mentioned there isn't any sense using cors within OnCall functions as the request will be already handled from a secured environment `server` and CORS is automatically handled by the onCall handler. I can see you haven't used `await` before `axios.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Phill mentioned in the comments, using `cors` in `OnCall` functions doesn’t make sense as those should be  already handled by `OnCall` handler.

```
return axios.get(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&locale=en",
);
```

Will not return any result as it will give `Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any\>\>` which isn’t the response to get the response use `await` or `.then` as follows:

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const testFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  functions.logger.info(data);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&locale=en"
      );
      functions.logger.info(response.data);
      return {
        status: 200,
        data: response.data,
      };
    } catch (err) {
      return {
        status: 500,
        error: err,
      };
    }
  }
);
```

If using firebase 2nd gen then :

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

export const todo = onCall({ cors: true }, async (request) => {
  functions.logger.info(request.data);
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&locale=en"
    );
    functions.logger.info(response.data);

    return {
      status: 200,
      data: response.data,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      status: 500,
      error: err,
    };
  }
});
```

Reference : **[Axios with async await](https://axios-http.com/docs/example#:%7E:text=//%20Want%20to%20use%20async/await%3F%20Add%20the%20%60async%60%20keyword%20to%20your%20outer%20function/method.)**